# How to use EV code signing token over RDP

Tags: windows, code-signing, rdp

In my setup, i have a Sectigo EV code signing token plugged into my local (windows) machine. From that machine, i log in over RDP to another (windows) maching (in azure). On both machines, i have the "SafeNet Client" Software installed.

On the remote machine, i do run builds in as part of these builds .exe files and DLLs get signed using the cert on the token. This worked flawlessly for the last couple of years.

Lately, i had to renew the code signing token and at the same time, also got a new development (local) machine.

Now when i try to sign (using the same code/batch jobs, etc. like before), the signing fails, because the cert cannot be found on the remote machine.

i do remember having done something "special" for the signing to work a couple of years ago, but i do not remember if this was something with rdp configuration, a domain policy, a firewall policy or some configuration of the sectigo token.

I already asked the Sectigo support and they deny this setup is possible at all, which is clearly not true.

Any ideas what i need to tweak in order to be able use my previous singning setup again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears nothing special has to be done, it 'just works'. I don't know why it did not work for me initially. However, i did uninstall the SafeNet Software on both the local machine and the remote machine and reinstalled. (First on the local machine, where the token is plugged in and next on the remote machine.)

No problems after that. No idea what caused the initial problems.

Comment: Can confirm that this scenario works and that having SafeNet Software installed both on the local machine and the remote machine performs redirection of the token into the RDP session.